Angular Material mat-nav-list active route
I'm discovering angular material, and I'm struggling to find the correct way of highlighting the activate route in the navigation component. I noticed it was not done by default in the navigation schematic.
I first wanted to do it myself with a custom class and routerLinkActive, like in a regular Angular application ... but I got some issues. Background-color worked fine, but color was overwritten by another material class, even if I add !important in my css.
So I tried to see if I did something wrong and realised there is actually a built in feature for that, with the activated property: https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#navigation-lists
However, I didn't understood the example of the doc. I have no idea what the list of links used in the @for is. After some more research, I managed to do what I want, but in a very ugly way:


<mat-nav-list>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/events" routerLinkActive 
        #rla1="routerLinkActive" [activated]="rla1.isActive">
        Events
    </a>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive 
        #rla2="routerLinkActive" [activated]="rla2.isActive">
        Contact
    </a>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/map" routerLinkActive 
        #rla3="routerLinkActive" [activated]="rla3.isActive">
        Map
    </a>
</mat-nav-list>



I'm sure it's supposed to be very simple, but I can't figure it out. If anyone knows how to make this cleaner, please let me know, I'd really appreciate it.

You can use the routerLinkActive option to pass a class added to the mat-list-item.
I you want the route to be an exact match, you can add [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
This whoud lead to somehting like so :
<mat-nav-list>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/events" routerLinkActive="active">
        Events
    </a>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">
        Contact
    </a>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/map" routerLinkActive="active">
        Map
    </a>
</mat-nav-list>

To customize the color, you can the add a special class to your css

.active {
   background: lightred;
   color: red;
}

With material, you can also override css variables to achieve your goal. In your case, the --mdc-list-list-item-label-text-color variable. You can see this looking through the chrome inspector, or using angular 19 through the styling documentation

.active {
   --mdc-list-list-item-label-text-color: red;
}


Thanks for the answer!
I wanted to use the activated property after discovering its existence, but if there is no clean/easy way to use it, I'll do that. Thanks again, the css variables override will like be very usefull!
